# Tomcat 7 cannot get a database connection with MySQL 5.5

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, ubuntu

When trying to access a servlet that reads from the database i get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 -
...
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.pdq.sms.db.DatabaseAccess.getConnection(DatabaseAccess.java:39)
    com.pdq.sms.db.DataRow.Read(DataRow.java:79)
    com.kessel.controllers.Home.doPost(Home.java:50)
    com.kessel.controllers.Home.doGet(Home.java:39)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.26 logs.
```

Looking in the Tomcat log files i find this : "Name testapp is not bound in this Context"

This is the relevant part of the **server.xml**

```
<Host name="myserver.org" appBase="webapps/test" 
      unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
   <Context path="/" docBase="testapp" reloadable="false">
      <Resource name="jdbc/testapp" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000"
          validationQuery="SELECT 1" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          username="myuser" password="mypass"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" />
    </Context>"
</Host>"
```

I've also modified the **04webapps.policy** to give the application permission to connect:

```
   permission java.net.SocketPermission "127.0.0.1:3306", "resolve, connect";
```

User is setup properly on the MySQL server, i can manually connect and select, insert etc on the database in question.

What am i not doing right ?

Comment: That NPE is just a bug in your own code. Please fix it first so that the real cause will be revealed. Perhaps you were incorrectly swallowing and suppressing any caught exceptions and continuing the code flow instead of throwing them outright?

Comment: @BalusC What makes you think it's bug in the code ? The same code works well on another server I have running with Tomcat 7 and MySQL 5.1. I haven't modified the code at all since that deployment.

Comment: Because it's a `RuntimeException` which originated in *your own* code (the `com.pdq.sms.db.DatabaseAccess` class is from your codebase, right?). Note that this bug isn't the cause of your concrete problem, but that it is *hiding* the real underlying problem. So if you fix that bug first, then the real underlying problem should be exposed by another, more clear, exception.

Comment: String resourceName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/testapp";
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup(resourceName);  And it seems like ds is null because getConnection() called on it throws the NPE. Now, i have this in a try/catch block for a NamingException (which is the only exception thrown by either IntialContext() or lookup() methods) which just prints out the exception's message which i though was : "Name testapp is not bound in this Context".

Comment: Fix that printing of the exception by throwing the exception outright. Your application must crash instead of continue with `null` variables. Okay, the real underlying cause is thus a `NamingException: Name testapp is not bound in this Context`?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. Even though i define that resource in server.xml

Comment: Is the mysql jar in the appropiate Tomcat folder?

Comment: Yes, i have "mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar" in the "/usr/share/tomcat7/lib" folder. I've even tried a couple of different connectors with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Change your resourceName ;

```
   java:comp/env/jdbc/testapp
```

to

```
  java://comp/env/jdbc/testapp
```

Comment: It makes no difference. There is no exception that is thrown on initial lookup (when the database code is first run). "Name testapp is not bound to this Context" comes from Tomcat and is logged when i try to access the database not when the application is loaded. I've tried moving the context definition in it's own context.xml file with no success either ...

Answer (score -1):

First write a jdbc code as a simple java proagram and don't forget to add the jdbc driver as external jar file.
And you can also **try by putting the jdbc jar file in tomcat lib folder or jre/lib/ext folder**, this is because when a servlet compiles it will take help of lib jar file in cse it in a 3rd party jar. if the jdbc connectivity code has no error it will run file after adding the jar file